# How to Build OOLua in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, lua, oolua

I'm currently trying to build OOLua in Visual Studio 2013. I have run the "premake4 vs2013" command and got a oolua.sln which looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zylvH.jpg

If I only build the oolua project is succeeds, but whenever I try to build the solution, I get a lot of errors everywhere. Am I supposed to build the whole solution or just the oolua project? How do I build the whole solution if that's what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have built the static library and that is all that is required. The solution includes all the tests, which if you want to run them requires Gmock and CppUnit.